# Scipy.minimize not correctly minimizing

Tags: python, scipy, minimization

I am currently doing a project that maps the velocity of stars as you move out from the center of the galaxy(the distance to the center is denoted by `r`).

Essentially, I am aiming to minimize the distance between my model function and my observed function. To do this, I have to minimize the function: `np.sum(((v_model-v_obs)/errors)**2)` where `errors` is an array of the error at each different `r` value. `v_obs` is the observed velocity at each `r` value  (`r` is just an array of numbers). To minimize the function, I have to manipulate `v_model` which can be done via manipulating two "fixing parameters" `p0` and `r0` in the equation (integrand is shown below):

```
np.sqrt(4.302*10**(-6)*quad(integrand,0,r.all(),args=(p0,r0))[0]/r.all())
```

Before I get into the problem, I want to know if `r.all()` is appropriate since it wouldn't allow me to put `r` due to it being an array. An alternative I had was to make an array of `v_model` via:

```
#am is the amount of elements in the array r 
#r, v_model,v_obs, and errors all have the same size
def integrand(r,p0,r0):
    return (p0 * r0**3)/((r+r0)*((r**2)+(r0**2)))*4*3.1415926535*r**2
integrals = []
for i in r:
     integrals.append(quad(integrand, 0 ,i,args=(p0,r0)))

v_model = []


for x in range (0,am):
    k = integrals[x][0]
    i = r[x]
    v_model.append(np.sqrt((4.302*10**(-6)*k)/i))
```

Regardless, to minimize the function `np.sum(((v_model-v_obs)/errors)**2)`
I tried to do something like this:

```
def chisqfunc(parameters):
    p0 = parameters[0]
    r0 = parameters[1]
    v_model = []
    for x in range(0,am):
        v_model.append(np.sqrt(4.302*10.0**(-6)*quad(integrand, 0, r[x], args=(p0,r0))[0]/r[x]))
    chisq = np.sum(((v_model-v_obs)/errors)**2)
    return chisq
x0 = np.array([10**6,24])
resolution = minimize(chisqfunc,x0)
```

However, the values I get back aren't good fits at all (which is evident when I graph the observed data and my model)

In conclusion, I have two main question:

1.) Is my function taking the model minus the observed at each different `r` value, and if not, how do I fix this? (I think I messed up my `v_model` equation)

2.) Why is it returning wrong numbers for `r0` and `p0`?

Here is my full code (By the way, to know if the minimization is working properly: r0 should be around 1.5 and p0 should be around: 3.5*10**8)

```
from scipy.optimize import*
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from scipy.integrate import quad

#number of measurements
am = 18


r0 = 1.8
p0 = 3.5*10**8.62

#Observed Data
v_obs = np.array([
234.00,
192.00,
212.00,
223.00,
222.00,
224.00,
224.00,
226.00,
226.00,
227.00,
227.00,
224.00,
220.00,
218.00,
217.00,
216.00,
210.00,
208.00



]
)

r = np.array([0.92, 
2.32,
3.24,   
4.17,   
5.10,   
6.03,   
6.96,   
7.89,   
8.80,   
9.73,   
10.64,
11.58,
12.52,
13.46,
14.40,
15.33,
16.27,
17.11


]
)

errors = np.array([
3.62,
4.31,
3.11,
5.5,
3.9,
3.5,
2.7,
2.5,
2.3,
2.1,
2.3,
2.6,
3.1,
3.2,
3.2,
3.1,
2.9,
2.8
    ])


#integral 
def integrand(r,p0,r0):
    return (p0 * r0**3)/((r+r0)*((r**2)+(r0**2)))*4*3.1415926535*r**2
integrals = []
for i in r:
     integrals.append(quad(integrand, 0 ,i,args=(p0,r0)))

v_model = []


for x in range (0,am):
    k = integrals[x][0]
    i = r[x]
    v_model.append(np.sqrt((4.302*10**(-6)*k)/i))


def chisqfunc(parameters):
    p0 = parameters[0]
    r0 = parameters[1]
    v_model = np.sqrt(4.302*10**(-6)*quad(integrand,0,r.all(),args=(p0,r0))[0]/r.all())
    chisq = np.sum(((v_model-v_obs)/errors)**2)
    print(v_model)
    return chisq
x0 = np.array([10**6,24])
resolution = minimize(chisqfunc,x0)
print("This is the function",resolution)
```

Let me know if I left out any data and thank you in advance!

Comment: ```By the way, to know if the minimization is working properly: r0 should be around 1.5 and p0 should be around: 3.5*10**8``` Well... using your code, your *optimal x* evaluates to ~```19k```. There is a solution ~ ```134.79``` and probably better ones. So do your own interpretations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change p0 in the function it brings the number down in the optimizer routine.  That seems to work well, I guess the numbers are so large it causes some numerical errors in the solver. Just remember to multiply the p0 answer by 3.85e+09, just like is done in the chisqfunc routine.

```
from scipy.optimize import*
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from scipy.integrate import quad
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
am = 18 # number of measurements
#Observed Data
v_obs = np.array([
234.00, 192.00, 212.00, 223.00, 222.00, 224.00, 224.00, 226.00, 226.00, 227.00, 
227.00, 224.00, 220.00, 218.00, 217.00, 216.00, 210.00, 208.00,
])
r = np.array([
 0.92,  2.32,  3.24,  4.17,  5.10,  6.03,  6.96,  7.89, 8.80, 9.73,   
10.64, 11.58, 12.52, 13.46, 14.40, 15.33, 16.27, 17.11
])
errors = np.array([
3.62, 4.31, 3.11, 5.5, 3.9, 3.5, 2.7, 2.5, 2.3, 2.1,
2.3, 2.6, 3.1, 3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 2.9, 2.8
])
grav_const = 4.302e-06
#print "np.pi, grav_const = " + str(np.pi) + ", " + str(grav_const)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
def func_to_integrate(rx, p0, r0):
    rho = (p0 * r0**3) / ( (rx + r0) * (rx**2 + r0**2) )
    function_result = rho * 4.0 * np.pi * rx**2
    #print "rx, p0, r0 = " + str(rx) + ", " + str(p0) + ", " + str(r0)
    return function_result
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
def simpsonsRule(func, a, b, n, p0, r0):
    if n%2 == 1:
        return "Not applicable"
    else:
        h = (b - a) / float(n)
        s = func(a, p0, r0) + sum((4 if i%2 == 1 else 2) * func(a+i*h, p0, r0) for i in range(1,n)) + func(b, p0, r0)
        return s*h/3.0
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
def chisqfunc(iter_vars):
    global v_model
    p0 = iter_vars[0] * 3.85e+09
    r0 = iter_vars[1]
    v_model = []
    for index in range(0, am):
        integral_result = simpsonsRule(func_to_integrate, 0.0, r[index], 200, p0, r0)
        v_mod_result = np.sqrt(grav_const * integral_result / r[index])
        v_model.append(v_mod_result)
    chisq = 0.0
    for index in range(0, am):
        chisq += ((v_model[index] - v_obs[index])/errors[index])**2
        #chisq += ((v_model[index] - v_obs[index]))**2
    chisq = np.sqrt(chisq)
    #chisq = np.sum(((v_model - v_obs)/errors)**2)
    print "chisq = " + str(chisq)
    #print "iterated p0, r0 = " + str(p0) + ", " + str(r0)
    return chisq
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
initial_guess = np.array([1.0, 2.0])
#initial_guess = np.array([3.5*10**8.62, 1.5])
#resolution = minimize(chisqfunc, initial_guess, method='TNC') # , tol=1e-12, options={'accuracy':0})
#resolution = minimize(chisqfunc, initial_guess, method='TNC', options={'rescale':-1})
#resolution = minimize(chisqfunc, initial_guess, method='CG')
resolution = minimize(chisqfunc, initial_guess, method='Nelder-Mead')
# # options tried
# 'gtol':1e-6, 'xtol':-1, 'rescale':0, 'ftol':0, 'accuracy':0, 'offset':None, 'scale':None
print("This is the function",resolution)
#print "resolution.x"
#print resolution.x
print "iterated p0 = " + str(resolution.x[0])
print "iterated p0 * 3.85e+09 = " + str(resolution.x[0] * 3.85e+09)
print "iterated r0 = " + str(resolution.x[1])
print "p0 should be about = " + str(3.5e+08)
print "r0 should be about = " + str(1.5)
print "-----------------------------------------------"
print "iterated model errors"
for index in range(0,am):
    print "v_obs, v_model, error = " + str(v_obs[index]) + ", " + str(v_model[index]) + ", " + str(v_obs[index] - v_model[index])
chisq = 0.0
for index in range(0, am):
    chisq += ((v_model[index] - v_obs[index])/errors[index])**2
    #chisq += ((v_model[index] - v_obs[index]))**2
chisq = np.sqrt(chisq)
print "iterated chisq = " + str(chisq)
print ""
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
print "model errors using p0 = 3.5*10**8.62, r0 = 1.8"
p0 = 3.5*10**8.62
r0 = 1.8
# chisq = 118 for p0 = 3.5*10**8.62, r0 = 1.8
# chisq = 564 for p0 = 3.5*10**8   , r0 = 1.5
chisq = 0.0
for index in range(0, am):
    integral_result = simpsonsRule(func_to_integrate, 0.0, r[index], 200, p0, r0)
    v_mod = np.sqrt(grav_const * integral_result / r[index])
    print "v_obs, v_mod, error = " + str(v_obs[index]) + ", " + str(v_mod) + ", " + str(v_obs[index] - v_mod)
    #chisq += ((v_mod - v_obs[index]))**2
    chisq += ((v_mod - v_obs[index])/errors[index])**2
chisq = np.sqrt(chisq)
print "using p0 = 3.5*10**8.62, r0 = 1.8, the chisq = " + str(chisq)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I found some others that are "normalizing" the parameters for better convergence:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369139/normalization-for-optimization-in-python
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072420/scipy-optimize-minimize-normalizing-parameters

Comment: Thank you so much! It works pretty much perfectly. I've been stuck on this for over a month, it's a relief to finally have it figured out. If you have the time, can you explain what you changed (in general)?

Comment: I noticed the p0 was a very large number and from past experience I know that solvers sometimes work better when the number are not too large or too small.  It is common to normalize inputs, that's why the p0 is multiplied by a factor that makes the answer close to 1.
I changed your quad integration to a simpson's rule for integration just because I'm more familiar with it, but I bet your method would work fine as well.
If you have any questions in particular, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing with your code.  I tried various methods/solvers and they all converge to about the same answer.  I'm thinking that this is the best answer it can reach.  To test this I calculated the root sum square of differences for the answer you say is right (r0 = 1.8, p0 = 3.5*10**8.62) and the computed answer.  The computed answer seems to have a smaller error (527 vs 564).

```
from scipy.optimize import*
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from scipy.integrate import quad
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#number of measurements
am = 18
r0 = 1.8
p0 = 3.5*10.0**8.62
#Observed Data
v_obs = np.array([
234.00, 192.00, 212.00, 223.00, 222.00, 
224.00, 224.00, 226.00, 226.00, 227.00, 
227.00, 224.00, 220.00, 218.00, 217.00, 
216.00, 210.00, 208.00,
])
r = np.array([
0.92, 2.32, 3.24, 4.17, 5.10,   
6.03, 6.96, 7.89, 8.80, 9.73,   
10.64, 11.58, 12.52, 13.46, 14.40,
15.33, 16.27, 17.11
])
errors = np.array([
3.62, 4.31, 3.11, 5.5, 3.9,
3.5, 2.7, 2.5, 2.3, 2.1,
2.3, 2.6, 3.1, 3.2, 3.2,
3.1, 2.9, 2.8
])
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#integral 
def integrand(r,p0,r0):
    return (p0 * r0**3)/((r+r0)*((r**2)+(r0**2)))*4.0*3.1415926535*r**2
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
integrals = []
for i in r:
    integrals.append(quad(integrand, 0, i, args=(p0,r0)))
#print "integrals = " + str(integrals)
v_model = []
for x in range(0,am):
    k = integrals[x][0]
    i = r[x]
    v_model.append(np.sqrt((4.302*10.0**(-6)*k)/i))
#print "v_model = " + str(v_model)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
def chisqfunc(parameters):
    p0 = parameters[0]
    r0 = parameters[1]
    v_model = np.sqrt(4.302*10.0**(-6)*quad(integrand, 0, r.all(), args=(p0,r0))[0]/r.all())
    chisq = np.sum(((v_model - v_obs)/errors)**2)
    #print "chisq = " + str(chisq)
    #print "v_model = " + str(v_model)
    return chisq
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
x0 = np.array([10.0**6,24.0]) # initial guess
# try various methods (they all give about the same answer, they all "converged")
#resolution = minimize(chisqfunc, x0, method='Nelder-Mead', tol=0.001)
#resolution = minimize(chisqfunc, x0, method='Powell', tol=0.001)
#resolution = minimize(chisqfunc, x0, method='CG', tol=0.001)
#resolution = minimize(chisqfunc, x0, method='BFGS', tol=0.001)
# Jac required - resolution = minimize(chisqfunc, x0, method='Newton-CG', tol=0.001)
#resolution = minimize(chisqfunc, x0, method='L-BFGS-B', tol=0.001)
#
resolution = minimize(chisqfunc, x0, method='TNC', tol=0.001, 
                      options={'scale':None})
# options tried
# 'gtol':1e-6, 'xtol':-1, 'rescale':0, 'ftol':0, 'accuracy':0, 'offset':None, 'scale':None
#
#resolution = minimize(chisqfunc, x0, method='COBYLA', tol=0.001)
#resolution = minimize(chisqfunc, x0, method='SLSQP', tol=0.001)
# Jac required - resolution = minimize(chisqfunc, x0, method='dogleg', tol=0.001)
# Jac required - resolution = minimize(chisqfunc, x0, method='trust-ncg', tol=0.001)
# unknown solver - resolution = minimize(chisqfunc, x0, method='trust-exact', tol=0.001)
# unknown solver - resolution = minimize(chisqfunc, x0, method='trust-krylov', tol=0.001)
print("This is the function",resolution)
print "resolution.x"
print resolution.x
print "p0 should be = " + str(3.5*10**8)
print "r0 should be = " + str(1.5)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# check answers to see which is better
for index in range(len(v_obs)):
    # declared answer---------------------------------------------------------
    p0 = 3.5*10**8
    r0 = 1.5
    integrals = []
    for i in r:
        integrals.append(quad(integrand, 0, i, args=(p0,r0)))
    #print "integrals = " + str(integrals)
    v_model_declared = []
    sum_error1 = 0.0
    for x in range(0,am):
        k = integrals[x][0]
        i = r[x]
        v_model_declared.append(np.sqrt((4.302*10.0**(-6)*k)/i))
        error1 = (v_obs[x] - v_model_declared[x])**2
        sum_error1 += error1
    #print "v_model = " + str(v_model)

    # computed answer---------------------------------------------------------
    p0 = 8.06400536e+06
    r0 = 4.27905063e+02
    integrals = []
    for i in r:
        integrals.append(quad(integrand, 0, i, args=(p0,r0)))
    #print "integrals = " + str(integrals)
    v_model_computed = []
    sum_error2 = 0.0
    for x in range(0,am):
        k = integrals[x][0]
        i = r[x]
        v_model_computed.append(np.sqrt((4.302*10.0**(-6)*k)/i))
        error2 = (v_obs[x] - v_model_computed[x])**2
        sum_error2 += error2

    print "v_obs, v_model, v_model2 = " + str(v_obs[index]) + ", " + str(v_model_declared[index])+ ", " + str(v_model_computed[index])
#
print "sum_error1 (declared answer) = " + str(sum_error1)
print "sum_error2 (computed answer) = " + str(sum_error2)
print "sqrt(sum_error1) (declared answer) = " + str(np.sqrt(sum_error1))
print "sqrt(sum_error2) (computed answer) = " + str(np.sqrt(sum_error2))
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: When I graph it with the optimized parameters, it's still very far from the observed velocities. It may be something wrong with my model function though, or I need to just put a bound on r0 since it's not really supposed to be much bigger than 70 or so.

Comment: I don' t understand what you're trying to do with r.all(), when I print r.all() it says "True".  Maybe that is the source of the problem.

Comment: Hmmm, I put `v_model = []
    for x in range(0,am):
        v_model.append(np.sqrt(4.302*10.0**(-6)*quad(integrand, 0, r[x], args=(p0,r0))[0]/r[x]))` Instead of   `v_model = np.sqrt(4.302*10.0**(-6)*quad(integrand, 0, r.all(), args=(p0,r0))[0]/r.all())`                                                          
  but now it returns something completely off. However, the chisqFunc seems to be working fine now. Like when I do `chisqfunc((3.5*10**8.2,1.8))` it returns a very low value as opposed to some different parameters

Comment: Can you show the equation and not the code for v_model?  It seems you want to integrate it over some interval? A little explanation of the math seems necessary at this point.

Comment: Here are the formulae, the variables are the same as they are in the program (r(0) = `r0`). Let me know if you need me to explain it further:                http://www.sciweavers.org/upload/Tex2Img_1512369140/render.png              (Nothing is cut off, I don't know why it scooted the integral so far right)

Comment: Wait, you have to multiply the integral by G (Gravitational constant) and divide the entire thing by r to get v_model. And then take the square root of the entire thing

Comment: What does this part come from? 
v_model = np.sqrt(4.302*10.0**(-6)*quad(integrand, 0, r.all(), args=(p0,r0))[0]/r.all())
For example, r.all() gives "True" because all of the elements are nonzero, but I don't think that is what you want.

Comment: Ya, I didn't mean to put that. Instead of that, put:                               
`v_model = [] for x in range(0,am): v_model.append(np.sqrt(4.302*10.0**(-6)*quad(integrand, 0, r[x], args=(p0,r0))[0]/r[x]))`

Comment: Here is the full formula for anyone who wants it, just plug in rho in the integral http://www.sciweavers.org/upload/Tex2Img_1512400275/render.png